# django-bower: `./manage.py bower install` (and variants) fail with KeyError: 'bower'

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

New to Django. I'm trying to clone and set up a pre-existing Django project which uses [django-bower](https://github.com/nvbn/django-bower). It uses Django 1.10.6 and django-bower 5.2.0.

I've set up a new virtualenv with all the project's requirements. The `manage.py` file is the same as the example from the django-bower library:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import os
import sys

if __name__ == "__main__":
    os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "example.settings")

    from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line

    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
```

Running `./manage.py bower install` (`bower_install`) too fails because Django and django-bower are only installed in the virtual environment. When I run it through `python manage.py bower install` or `python manage.py bower_install` I get this stack trace:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 189, in fetch_command
    app_name = commands[subcommand]
KeyError: 'bower'
```

Comment: Did you add it to your `INSTALLED_APPS`, etc?

Comment: Yes, `'djangobower'` is in `INSTALLED_APPS`,  `"djangobower.finders.BowerFinder"` is in `STATICFILES_FINDERS`,  and `BOWER_COMPONENTS_ROOT` is defined.

Comment: When you type `./manage.py help`, does it list a `bower` command in the list of commands? Is there a `bower` section? If there isn't, it sounds like it isn't being picked up in `INSTALLED_APPS`. The next step if it is would be to go into your virtualenv and make sure that the pip installed `django-bower` app has a file called `management/commands/bower.py`.

Comment: @FlipperPA Thank you - this works! The issue seems to be that I needed a `SECRET_KEY` environment variable defined, which wasn't in our setup documentation.